# Find value of a Key in nested JSON using underscore where some key name changes

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

Hi I have a JSON object that look like this:

```
var data = {
  req: {
    id: 1,
    name: "daniel",
    details:{ 
      address: "201 sd f",
      city: "dshed"
    }
  },
  ack: "Success"
}
```

Now I want to get the value of key `ack`. Does anyone know how to get value of `ack` using underscore? The problem is that the key name `req` may change based on data. there is only one key fixed which is `ack` and I want the value of this.

Comment: is that repeated multiple times or is this it? `data.ack` would do the trick wouldn't it?

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

`data.ack` is all you need. If you must do it using underscore

```
_.values(_.pick(data, 'ack'))[0]
```

Seems like an overkill if you ask me.